# How do I check if some elements of sublist exists in list (Python)?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have a list, for example like this below:

```
list=[['a',0,1200],['b',1,900],['c',2,500],['a',1,200]]
```

and I need to check if these sub-lists contain the same element, for this example suppose to find the first element of each sub-list, so It will be found that `['a',1,200]` was the same with `['a',0,1200]`,
because their first element are 'a'

So how do I find out all the duplicated sub-lists?

Comment: Can you share the expected output and maybe some code?

Comment: I have no idea how to write these code, just a thought like this:
for i in list:
    while i[0] in list... #to check if current first element exist in the list

Answer (score 0):

```
list[0] in list [1]
```

(in your case is False.)
for exemple you can check if first list in sec list.
if you want to check spcific (compere letter)
you can use to "extract" the list:

```
for x in list:
print(x)
```

and if you want to compare spcific the fisrt letter, but not all the sub-list.

```
counter = 0
for x in list:
  for i in list:
    if i != x and i[0] in x[0]:
        counter += 0.5
```

(sorry about my english)

Comment: may I know why you use counter variable and plus 0.5 each time?

Comment: its beacuse is count twice. its check all the list, so one from the first, and one from the sec. So I divided it by 2 (and that mean 1/2 = 0.5)